# How to apply a function to a sequence of dicts?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I have the following function:

```
def count_chars(e):
    return len(e)
```

I am iterating a json as follows:

In:

```
a_lis = []
with open('../JSON_FILE.json','r') as fa:
    a = json.load(fa)
    for e in a['entries']:
        pprint(e)
```

Out:

```
{'data': ['string'], 'type': 'one'}
{'data': ['a string '], 'type': 'one'}
{'data': ['another string'], 'type': 'three'}
...
{'data': ['one more string'], 'type': 'two'}
```

How can I apply `count_chars` function and add it or update it as a new string in the `'data'` list? For instance the expected output would look like:

```
{'data': ['string','6'], 'type': 'one'}
{'data': ['a string','8'], 'type': 'one'}
{'data': ['another string','14'], 'type': 'three'}
...
{'data': ['one more string','15'], 'type': 'two'}
```

**UPDATE**:

I found that my lists have more than one item, for example: `['first', 'second string']`? How can I return `['first', len_1, 'second string', len_2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `append()`:

```
lst = [
    {"data": ["string"], "type": "one"},
    {"data": ["a string "], "type": "one"},
    {"data": ["another string"], "type": "three"},
]

def count_chars(e):
    return len(e)

for d in lst:
    d["data"].append(count_chars(d["data"][0]))

print(lst)
# [{'data': ['string', 6], 'type': 'one'}, {'data': ['a string ', 9], 'type': 'one'}, {'data': ['another string', 14], 'type': 'three'}]
```

If you have more strings in the list, you can use `extend()` and rebuild a new list:

```
lst = [
    {"data": ["string", "hi"], "type": "one"},
    {"data": ["a string "], "type": "one"},
    {"data": ["another string"], "type": "three"},
]

def count_chars(e):
    return len(e)

for d in lst:
    newlst = []
    for x in d["data"]:
        newlst.extend([x, count_chars(x)])
    d["data"] = newlst

print(lst)
# [{'data': ['string', 6, 'hi', 2], 'type': 'one'}, {'data': ['a string ', 9], 'type': 'one'}, {'data': ['another string', 14], 'type': 'three'}]
```

**Note:** Since `count_chars()` simply returns `len()`, it might be easier to just call `len()` itself.

Answer (score 2):

That should work :)

```
def count_chars(e):
    return len(e)

a_lis = []
with open('../JSON_FILE.json','r') as fa:
    a = json.load(fa)
    for e in a['entries']:
        for String in e["data"]: # Grab one string inside the strings list.
            if type(String) == int:
                continue # Skip the count chars value that you appended.
            Length = count_chars(String) # Apply the function.
            e["data"].append(Length) # Append the returned value to the data list containing the string.

        # Now we reorder the list from ["a", "ab", "abc", 1, 2, 3] to ["a", 1, "ab", 2, "abc", 3]
        strings_found = int(len(e["data"])/2)
        reordered_list = []

        for start in range(0, strings):
            reordered_list = reordered_list + [x for x in e["data"][start::strings_found ]]
        e["data"] = reordered_list
```

Comment: What if I have more than one element in my list? for example: `['first', 'second string']`? How can I return `['first', len_1, 'second string', len_2]`

Comment: I got: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
`

Comment: My bad I miswrote something, now it properly skips the numbers. Though it results in  `['first', 'second string', len_1, len_2]`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: After we are done with creating the new list `['first', 'second string', len_1, len_2]` we can go back to `['first', len_1, 'second string', len_2]` with a little more work, I'll edit to show you how.

Comment: It does, thanks. I was using `enumerate()` to only process every other element and skip the appended lengths, but I found `type()==int` more convenient in the end and forgot to remove the enumerate.